# Ubuntu 14.04 not discovering wireless router

Tags: wireless, 14.04

My Ubuntu version 14.04 suddenly stopped discovering my comcast wireless router. I can see other routers. I can also connect to it by "Connect to a Hidden WIFI Network..".

Is this a router configuration issue?

Below is the ubuntu release  and wireless hardware information.

```
cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"

add wireless hardware
##### lspci #####

06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM4311 802.11b/g Wireless LAN Controller [103c:1363]
Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
```

Comment: further steps.. ran "sudo apt-get update" and "sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree".  no change

Comment: Well, you said it yourself that you can connect to a hidden network, right?  So it's definitely the router settings

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I checked the router configuration and the "Broadcast Network Name (SSID)" is enabled and I can see the router on many other devices (phones, WII, in fact another ubuntu machine with the exact same version of the os but different wireless card (Qualcomm Atheros AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)).  I think something is broke in the driver.

Comment: I should have also noted I'm still using the b43-pci-bridge kernel driver.  I'm not sure how to replace it with the linux-firmware-nonfree install.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the tutorial here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43%20-%20Internet%20access

Follow the instructions for your 4311. I have the 4318 and that page got mine working just fine.